# Parsing condition string into R function body

Tags: r

I would like to create a data cleaning rule based on few dependencies within columns. For example, if Q3 is 3 than I need to check if Q1 is blank. I can do it with a simple command like this:

```
df$Q1chk<-ifelse(df$Q3==3 & is.na(df$Q1), 1,0)
```

where 1 in final Q1chk means that it is ok. Now, as I have a lot of conditions and columns I would like to have more flexible and elegant solution. So first I would like to assign a "filter" check into column like this: `attr(df$Q1, "filter")<-"Q3==3"`, and then run a function on the entire dataset. And condition might be different than with "==" operator.

How to pass a string condition "Q3==3" to the function, to make it working. I tried with sth like:

```
ChkF<-function(dat, var) {
  exp<- attr(dat[[var]], "filter")
  dat[[paste0("chk",var)]]<- ifelse(is.na(dat[[var]]) & dat[eval(rlang::parse_expr(exp))==TRUE], 1 , 0)
}
```

but it doesn't work. I know that expression: `dat[["Q3"]]==3` works fine, but simply replacing quotes with square brackets (from "Q3==3" to [["Q3"]]==3) doesn't look like elegant solution. Is there any more suitable approach?
Finally I would like to use many conditions in conjunction for one column e.g.: `attr(df$Q1, "filter")<-c("Q3==3", "Q4>1", "Q5 %in% 2:7")`, so that's why I would like to keep syntax for the condition as simple as possible.

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
##
#   made up example
#
dt <- data.table(Q3=rpois(100, 3), Q4=rnorm(100, 1), Q5=rnbinom(100, mu=7, size=50))
##
#  you start here
#
filters <- lapply(c("Q3==3", "Q4>1", "Q5 %in% 2:7"), str2expression)
dt[, lapply(filters, \(x) as.integer(eval(x))), by=.(Q3, Q4, Q5)]
##     Q3          Q4 Q5 V1 V2 V3
##  1:  2  1.39810588  7  0  1  1
##  2:  2  0.38797361  4  0  0  1
##  3:  3  1.34111969  7  1  1  1
##  4:  5 -0.12936310  7  0  0  1
##  5:  2  2.43302370  5  0  1  1
##  6:  5  2.98039990 10  0  1  0
##  ...
```